# How to grab values using PHP switch statements?

Tags: php, html, select, switch-statement

I have html select box in which I want to grab the value of the selected parameter. When a button is clicked, I want the values from the selected parameters to be inserted into a `shell_exec()` as arguments. I need this because these arguments (selected parameters) change the function of a python script, giving a different result based on the parameters (using argparse).

html select code (in visual.php):

```
 <form method="post" action="main.php>
 <input type="button" name="visual" value="Visualize" id="myBtn" class="visualize-btn">
    <select name="samplingStep" class="select">
                   <option value="1">1%</option>
                   <option value="5">5%</option>
                   <option value="10">10%</option>
                   <option selected="selected" value="20">20%</option>
                   <option value="40">40%</option>
                 </select>
    </form>
```

php code used in 2 files: (if this can be achieved without php, please suggest)

visual.php:

```
  $select3 = $_POST['samplingStep'];
      switch ($select3) {
        case '1':
            $samplingStep = '1';
            break;
        case '5':
            $samplingStep = '5';
            break;
        case '10':
            $samplingStep = '10';
            break;
        case '20':
            $samplingStep = '20';
            break;
        case '40':
            $samplingStep = '40';
            break;
        default:
            $samplingStep = '20';
            break;
        }
```

main.php:

```
<?php
include 'visual.php';
$output = shell_exec(whoami);
echo $output;
echo (" ");
echo $samplingStep;
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $.post("main.php", function(data, status) {
      $("#visual").html(data);
      alert(status);
    })
    doSomething()
  });

});
```

while using `var_dump($_POST);` I get the results of:

**array** (size=0)
   empty

**THE ISSUE**

The problem with this code is that the switch statement in the php is not correct. I currently have them echoing out to see if they have the correct values, but it always changes to the default option, meaning that the POST method is wrong, or the code in general is wrong.

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

I expect that when this code is completed, I can echo out $samplingStep and once the button is clicked, it'll echo out (for example) 40% when 40% is selected in the selector.

Comment: When posting a question, you must include the actual issue you're having or we have no idea what you're asking us about. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You need to provide us with your attempt, example data, expected results and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: Also, `shell_exec(whoami)` should be `shell_exec('whoami')`.

Comment: Thank you for your first comment, I did not clearly state my problem. I believe that I now addressed that in my edit.

For the `shell_exec` comment, it still does work with `whoami` not in single quotes. `''`

Comment: In PHP, `whoami` will be read as a constant. If it doesn't find a constant with that name, it fallbacks to use it as a string. Currentlly, that works, but in future versions, it will throw a real error for it. The only reason you're not seeing _"Warning: Use of undefined constant whoami -  - assumed 'whoami' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"_ is because you're either have display errors turned off or you don't have your error reporting level set to show warnings.

Comment: Before your `switch/case`, do a `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you're actually getting. Add the output to your question as well. You should also post the complete form. Are you posting it as a normal form or are you using JS/Aajx? We need to see the complete flow. There's nothing in the posted code that would explain your issue.

Comment: The reality is, is that `whoami` is not the issue of my problem. That code will eventually be swapped out with `'sh test.sh $samplingStep etc. etc.'`. The `whoami` code is just being used as an example for now. Posted the var_dump results.

Comment: Cann't you replace your switch block with $samplingStep = $_POST['samplingStep'];

Comment: Would that retract the value of the selected option? For example, if 40% was selected and had the value of '40', would `$samplingStep = $_POST['samplingStep'];` in result be equal to '40'?

Comment: It does not look like you are passing any parameters in your JQuery post. Take a look at the JQuery docs to see how you can add params. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/